# Raise For-Loop Limit

Tags: python, for-loop, range

```
x=4

for i in range(1, x):
    try:
        ...
    except:
        x+=1
```

The range is

1

2

3

4

And then it stops.

I want the cap to be increased when the exception occurs.

Comment: Increasing `x` inside the loop won't alter the number of iterations, because the range  object created by calling `range()` was created at the beginning of the loop and isn't modified.

Comment: You fundamentally misunderstand the nature of a Python for-loop. Python for-loops are *iterator based for loops*. `for x in <something>:` requires `<something>` to be an *iterable*, i.e. something that can create an *iterator* when you call `iter(something)`. You used a `range(1, 4)` object, which is iterable. Changing the variable `x` will not magically mutate the iterator or the `range` iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the loop limit to change dynamically, then you need to use a `while` loop:

```
x = 4
i = 1
while i < x:
    try:
        ...
    except:
        x += 1
```